# typescript module resolution

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

Is there a typescript module resolution strategy that would allow me to have both local imports **not** starting with a slash and imports from node_modules in the same module?

With "moduleResolution" set to "node" the compiler cannot find my local modules, with all other options it does not see the modules in node_modules directory I'm trying to import.

I have the following imports in my file:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Logger} from "core/logging/Logger";
```

"angular2/core" is located in node_modules, "core/logging/Logger" is my local module.

I think that should be possible, if you look at angular's code they seem to have both, ie. in the http.ts module:  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'; //this is local
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; //this probably comes from node_modules
```

More background info:
I have a project consisting of two subprojects:
 - library
 - app
Library defines some utilities which app then uses. My build process first builds the 'library' subproject, then copies it (compiled js along with d.ts files) to 'library' subfolder in 'app's node_modules, then compiles the 'app'.

In 'library' I have the following classes:

```
//file project/library/jsonparser/JSONParser.ts
class JSONParser {...} 

//file project/library/services/ConfigurationService.ts
import {JSONParser} from "../jsonparser/JSONParser"
class ConfigurationService {
  constructor(parser: JSONParser){ ... }
}
```

In 'app':

```
import {JSONParser} from "library/jsonparser/JSONParser" //this comes from node_modules in 'app'
import {ConfigurationService} from "library/services/ConfigurationService" //from node_modules
class AppConfigurationService extends ConfigurationService {
  constructor(parser: JSONParser) {
    super(parser);
  }
}
```

This won't compile as soon as JSONParser has any non public fields (they are imported from two different places so for typescript these are two different types). That is why I'm trying two import my modules without the slash at the start. But maybe there are other solutions to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that should be possible, if you look at angular's code they seem to have both, ie. in the http.ts module: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts

Not Trivial.

They have module resolution `classic` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6b73d09ba1d8c227d1b297341de2218aea5d1276/modules/angular2/tsconfig.json#L12

> import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; //this probably comes from node_modules

The have a non trivial build pipeline specific to them that maps this to `node_modules`. See : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/851647334040ec95d1ab2f376f6b6bb76ead0d9a/tools/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.ts#L271