# How to require files relative to root?

Tags: typescript

With normal `node` JavaScript you can set `NODE_PATH` and require local modules. For example given:

```
project
  node_modules
  src
    library
      index.js
```

You can set `NODE_PATH=src` and `require("library")` anywhere in the code base. How can the same be accomplished with `tsconfig.json`?

I've read the [module resolutions page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), and tried the following configs.

```
{
  baseUrl: "src"
}

{
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    "*": [
       "*",
       "src/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

In each case, it can't find the modules in `src`. I set `--allowJs` flag and when I change to relative imports `../library` it works fine.

---

The equivalent in [webpack `resolve.root`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root).

```
// webpack.config.js

resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve("./src")
  ]
}
```

The equivalent in [flow `[options]`](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#options).

```
# .flowconfig

[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=src
```

Related questions:

- [Absolute module path resolution in TypeScript files in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606571/absolute-module-path-resolution-in-typescript-files-in-vscode/40177442#40177442)
- [root path for typescript module resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535460/root-path-for-typescript-module-resolution)
- [typescript module resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766219/typescript-module-resolution)

Related issues:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
}
```

Comment: It's the ```"baseUrl": "src"``` line that answers the question. Thanks for posting it.