# How to set up absolute module import to TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

What is the "best" way to enable absolute import paths, i.e.

```
import { my_module } from 'src/my_module_file';
```

There's [conflicting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168500/how-to-require-files-relative-to-root) on this; [some](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12597) claiming that this can be achieved with `baseUrl` and `paths` settings in `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions`, and some people claiming the opposite. As a TypeScript newbie, I'm slightly confused.

Do I need to setup [Webpack with resolve.modules setting](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules), or is there a feature in TypeScript compiler for converting absolute paths to relative paths during compilation?

Tried this kind of tsconfig.json without luck:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["./*"]
        },
        "rootDir": "server",
        "outDir": "generated",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "include": [
        "server/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

ps. using Node.js and running my app with ts-node.